# Can't get linking multiple functions and a class to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I have a program which holds many functions and I have no idea how to link them together :/

When I'm working on the python's shell everything is working fine because everything is in one definition but when I divide them into different definitions it doesn't work.

I have a different Metals each one of them has a weight and value and a name, etc. I want to make a class for those metals and then sort them in a descending order based on there `valuePerBar` once and `valuePerWeight` once

those are my metals :

- Gold, 1 bar, 5 weight per bar, 750 value per bar
- Silver, 1 bar, 1 weight per bar, 400 value per bar
- Rhodium, 1 bar, 4 weight per bar, 500 value per bar
- Platinum, 1 bar, 6 weight per bar, 1000 value per bar

and this is the my class:

```
class Metal(rit_object):
    """
    Represents a single metal type, composed of:
    :slot name (str): The name of the metal
    :slot totalBars (int): The total number of bars
    :slot weightPerBar (int): The weight of a single bar
    :slot valuePerBar (int): The value of a single bar
    :slot valuePerWeight (float): The value per weight of the metal
    :slot barsTaken (int): The number of bars added to the satchel
    """

    __slots__ = ( 'name' ,  'totalBars' , 'weightPerBar', 'valuePerBar', 'valuePerWeight', 'barsTaken'  )
    _types = ( str , int , int, int, float, int )
```

Note: `rit_object` is a private class which makes my work easier and all it does is to put types for each parameter ! ex: name --> str and totalBars --> int ..etc

the way I am doing the sorting in the shell is :

```
class Metal(rit_object):
    """
    Represents a single metal type, composed of:
    :slot name (str): The name of the metal
    :slot totalBars (int): The total number of bars
    :slot weightPerBar (int): The weight of a single bar
    :slot valuePerBar (int): The value of a single bar
    :slot valuePerWeight (float): The value per weight of the metal
    :slot barsTaken (int): The number of bars added to the satchel
    """

    __slots__ = ( 'name' ,  'totalBars' , 'weightPerBar', 'valuePerBar', 'valuePerWeight', 'barsTaken'  )
    _types = ( str , int , int, int, float, int )

    platinum = Metal("platinum", 1, 6, 1000, 166.666667, 0 )
    gold = Metal("gold", 1, 5, 750, 150.0, 0 )
    rhodium = Metal("rhodium", 1, 4, 500, 125.0, 0 )
    silver = Metal("silver", 1, 1, 4, 400.0, 0 )


    Metals = [
        Metal("platinum", 1, 6, 1000, 166.666667, 0 ),
        Metal("gold", 1, 5, 750, 150.0, 0 ) ,
        Metal("rhodium", 1, 4, 500, 125.0, 0 ),
        Metal("silver", 1, 1, 4, 400.0, 0 )
        ]

def getKey(Metal):
    return name.valuePerBar

sorted(customlist, key=getKey, reverse=True)
```

and everything works perfect, now I want to make a program with multiple definition to make it well-organiezed but my problems is I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO LINK THE FUNCTIONS !!

this is my program:

```
"""
Author: Sean Strout (sps@cs.rit.edu)
Author: <<< YOUR NAME HERE >>>

This class represents the types of metal bars that Greedo can
store in his satchel.  Each type of bar is a separate Metal
object.  This module also has routines that work with metals,
e.g. creation, reading from a file, and sorting based on 
various criteria.

Language: Python 3
"""

from rit_object import *            # rit_object class

class Metal(rit_object):
    """
    Represents a single metal type, composed of:
    :slot name (str): The name of the metal
    :slot totalBars (int): The total number of bars
    :slot weightPerBar (int): The weight of a single bar
    :slot valuePerBar (int): The value of a single bar
    :slot valuePerWeight (float): The value per weight of the metal
    :slot barsTaken (int): The number of bars added to the satchel
    """

    __slots__ = ( 'name' ,  'totalBars' , 'weightPerBar', 'valuePerBar', 'valuePerWeight', 'barsTaken'  )
    _types = ( str , int , int, int, float, int )


def createMetal(name, totalBars, weightPerBar, valuePerBar):
    """
    Create and return a new Metal object.
    :param name (str): The name of the metal
    :param totalBars (int): The total number of bars
    :param weightPerBar (int): The weight of a single bar
    :param valuePerBar (int): The value of a single bar
    :return: A newly initialized Metal object
    :rtype: Metal
    """
    platinum = Metal("platinum", 1, 6, 1000, 166.666667, 0 )
    gold = Metal("gold", 1, 5, 750, 150.0, 0 )
    rhodium = Metal("rhodium", 1, 4, 500, 125.0, 0 )
    silver = Metal("silver", 1, 1, 4, 400.0, 0 )


def readMetals(Metals):

    """
    Read the metals from a file whose format is:
        metalName totalBars weightPerBar valuePerBar
    :param fileName (str): The name of the file
    :return: A list of Metal objects
    :rtype: list
    """


    Metals = [
        Metal("platinum", 1, 6, 1000, 166.666667, 0 ),
        Metal("gold", 1, 5, 750, 150.0, 0 ) ,
        Metal("rhodium", 1, 4, 500, 125.0, 0 ),
        Metal("silver", 1, 1, 4, 400.0, 0 )
        ]

print (name.valuePerBar)

def getKey(Metal):
    return name.valuePerBar

def sortMetalsByValuePerBar():
    """
    Sort the metals by value per bar using insertion sort.  The list of
    metals is modified in place to be ordered by value per bar.
    :param metals (list of Metal): The list of metals
    :return: None
    :rtype: NoneType
    """

    return sorted(Metals, key=getKey, reverse=True)


def getKey2(Metal):
        return name.weightPerBar

def sortMetalsByValuePerWeight(metals):

    """
    Sort the metals by value per weight using insertion sort.  The list of
    metals is modified in place to be ordered by value per weight.
    :param metals (list of Metal): The list of metals
    :return: None
    :rtype: NoneType"""

    return sorted(Metals, key=getKey, reverse=True)


def printMetals(metals):
    """
    Display the metals to standard output.
    :param metals (list of Metal): The list of metals
    :return: None
    :rtype: NoneType
    """
    if Q == a:
        getKey(Metal)
        sortMetalsByValuePerBar()
    else:
        getKey2(Metal)
        sortMetalsByValuePerWeight(metals)


Q = input ("Enter 'a' for descending order or 'b' for ascending order")

Metal(rit_object)
createMetal(name, totalBars, weightPerBar, valuePerBar)
readMetals(Metals)
printMetals(metals)
```

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: is how to link those functions in order to work as they are working in the shell !

Comment: "it's not working" is a little vague... what do you expect to happen, what is happening instead, and what have you tried?

Comment: I expect the metals to be sorted like this : Metal( name: Platinum, totalBars: 1, weightPerBar: 6, valuePerBar: 1000,
valuePerWeight: 166.66666666666666, barsTaken: 0 )
Metal( name: Gold, totalBars: 1, weightPerBar: 5,
valuePerBar: 750, valuePerWeight: 150.0, barsTaken: 0 )
Metal( name: Rhodium, totalBars: 1, weightPerBar: 4,
valuePerBar: 500, valuePerWeight: 125.0, barsTaken: 0 )
Metal( name: Silver, totalBars: 1, weightPerBar: 1, valuePerBar: 400,
valuePerWeight: 400.0, barsTaken: 0 ) and this happens when I write the code in the shell but when I divide it into functions it doesn't

Comment: "Linking functions together" is not a term used in python, so I am still unclear what you want.  Can you describe in different words?  Are you asking how to make the functions in to class methods?

Comment: can you please give me your email or any other way to contact you so we can have a better discussion environment ?

Comment: otherwise what I want to do is : to list the Metals in a descending order based on there value per bar which is 1000 for platinum, 750 for gold ..etc but I want to do this in the same structure I posted above